# Casting in generic abstract class that implements interface

Tags: c#, generics

Given a base class `Coin`

```
public class Coin { }
```

and two derived classes `Coin50Cent` and `Coin25Cent`

```
public class Coin50 : Coin { }
public class Coin25 : Coin { }
```

The task is to create an object of a `CoinMachine` (used for coin exchange, e.g. puting 50 cent coin returns two 25 cent coins) that corresponds the following requierments:

1. `CoinMachine` must have two collections of `Coin25Cent` and `Coin50cent` objects.
2. The collections must be derived from an abstract generic class `CoinStack<T>` that has two methods

   `void Push(T item);
   T Pop();`
3. `CoinMachine` must work as follows

   `CoinMachine.Push(new Coin25()); // puts 25cent in 25c stack
   CoinMachine.Push(new Coin50()); // puts 50cent in 50c stack
   CoinMachine.Pop();      // gets 50cent from 50c stack
   CoinMachine.Pop();      // gets 25cent from 25c stack`

Here's my implementation
Seems like I have a problem with casting in abstract CoinStack class.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    /* Given condition */
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CoinMachine.Push(new Coin25());
            CoinMachine.Push(new Coin50());
            CoinMachine.Pop<Coin50>();
            CoinMachine.Pop<Coin25>();
        }
    }

    public class Coin { }
    public class Coin50 : Coin { }
    public class Coin25 : Coin { }
    /* End given condition */

    public interface ICoinStack
    {
        T Pop<T>();
        void Push<T>(T item);
    }

    /* The problem within this abstract class */
    public abstract class CoinStack<T> : ICoinStack
    {
        private Queue<T> _stack = new Queue<T>();

        public T Pop<T>() { return _stack.Dequeue(); }
        public void Push<T>(T item) { _stack.Enqueue(item); }
    }

    public class CoinStack50 : CoinStack<Coin50> { }
    public class CoinStack25 : CoinStack<Coin25> { }

    public class CoinMachine
    {
        private static Dictionary<Type, ICoinStack> map;

        static CoinMachine()
        {
            map = new Dictionary<Type, ICoinStack>()
            {
                { typeof(Coin50), new CoinStack50() },
                { typeof(Coin25), new CoinStack25() }
            };
        }

        public static T Pop<T>()
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            return map[type].Pop<T>();
        }

        public static void Push<T>(T item)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            map[type].Push(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to use type constraints on `CoinStack<T>` like this: `CoinStack<T> where T: Coin`. You will have to add the same on your `CoinMachine.Push` and `Pop` methods too. This will increase the type safety of your code, but I doubt it will fix the problem.

Comment: You could just keep a collection of `Coin` instead of their derived types. What you could then do is push your `Coin25` and `Coin50` objects to that stack, and retrieve them later as their actual supertypes.

Comment: @aevitas, I'd assume the OP does this on purpose as s/he needs separate collections per coin type

Comment: @Ivaylo Slavov, aevitas thanks for replies, but  Ivaylo Slavov is absolutely right. The CoinMachine must contain separate collections for each coin type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `ICoinStack` has generic methods, like `Push<T>(T item)`, which basically says that an implementation of `ICoinStack` can accept an `item` of *any* type.

However, in your implementation `CoinStack<T>`, you want to limit `<T>` of `ICoinStack.Push<T>` to `<T>` of `CoinStack<T>`. The compiler should have already given you a warning, saying the type parameter `T` has the same name as the type parameter `T` of the outer type.

You have to fix your design, either by making `ICoinStack` itself generic (as in `ICoinStack<T>`), or change it's method to accept/return `object` (or even better: `Coin`) instead of `T`.

**Example:**

```
// accept/return Coin instead of T to keep ICoinStack
// and it's methods non-generic
public interface ICoinStack
{
   Coin Pop();
   void Push(Coin item);
}

// explicit interface implementation and the where T:Coin 
// constrain help us here to implement ICoinStack
public abstract class CoinStack<T> : ICoinStack where T:Coin
{
   private Queue<T> _stack = new Queue<T>();

   Coin ICoinStack.Pop() { return _stack.Dequeue(); }
   void ICoinStack.Push(Coin item) { _stack.Enqueue((T)item); }

   public T Pop() { return _stack.Dequeue(); }
   public void Push(T item) { _stack.Enqueue(item); }
}

// we need a cast in Pop<T>, and also the where T:Coin constrain
public class CoinMachine
{
   private static Dictionary<Type, ICoinStack> map;

   static CoinMachine()
   {
       map = new Dictionary<Type, ICoinStack>()
       {
           { typeof(Coin50), new CoinStack50() },
           { typeof(Coin25), new CoinStack25() }
       };
   }

   public static T Pop<T>() where T:Coin
   {
       var type = typeof(T);
       return (T)map[type].Pop();
   }

   public static void Push<T>(T item) where T:Coin
   {
       var type = typeof(T);
       map[type].Push(item);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to change this code:

```
public interface ICoinStack
{
    T Pop<T>();
    void Push<T>(T item);
}
```

to this:

```
public interface ICoinStack
{
    Coin Pop();
    void Push(Coin item);
}
```

and the implementation as follows:

```
public abstract class CoinStack<T> : ICoinStack where T: Coin
{
    private Queue<T> _stack = new Queue<T>();

    public T Pop() { return _stack.Dequeue(); }
    Coin ICoinStack.Pop() {return this.Pop(); }
    public void Push(T item) { _stack.Enqueue(item); }
    void ICoinStack.Push(Coin item) { this.Push((T) item);
}
```

The problem was that your code allowed to use a single `CoinStack` instance with different `Coin` implementations. When you specify generics for the entire type (the entire `CoinStack<T>`, you enforce the same type to be used within the class methods (`Push` and `Pop` will only accept the same T, not any type, also notice they do not need a `<T>` anymore.)

Notice also the generic type constraints (see also my comment below your question). These constrains ensure that you only call `Push` and `Pop` with an instance of the `Coin` class (opposing to the previous code that can have any type passed trough), and thus, have improved type safety.

In your `CoinMachine` class, you must edit the `Push` and `Pop` methods as follows:

```
    // notice the generic constraint, as it is required now by the compiler
    public static T Pop<T>() where T: Coin 
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        // we need a cast, as the `ICoinStack` now return `Coin`
        return (T) map[type].Pop();
    }

    public static void Push<T>(T item) where T: Coin
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        map[type].Push(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would solve it:

```
public class Coin { }
public class Coin50 : Coin { }
public class Coin25 : Coin { }
/* End given condition */

public interface ICoinStack
{
    T Pop<T>() where T: Coin;
    void Push<T>(T item) where T: Coin;
}

/* The problem within this abstract class */
public abstract class CoinStack : ICoinStack
{
    private Queue<Coin> _stack = new Queue<Coin>();

    public TCoin Pop<TCoin>() where TCoin: Coin { return (TCoin)_stack.Dequeue(); }
    public void Push<TCoin>(TCoin item) where TCoin: Coin { _stack.Enqueue(item); }
}

public class CoinStack50 : CoinStack { }
public class CoinStack25 : CoinStack { }

public class CoinMachine
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, ICoinStack> map;

    static CoinMachine()
    {
        map = new Dictionary<Type, ICoinStack>()
        {
            { typeof(Coin50), new CoinStack50() },
            { typeof(Coin25), new CoinStack25() }
        };
    }

    public static T Pop<T>() where T: Coin
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        return map[type].Pop<T>();
    }

    public static void Push<T>(T item) where T: Coin
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        map[type].Push(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: the condition of the task requiers the abstract CoinStack class to be generic :)